# Why money cast does not work in filament Resource Hint text?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Using money cast class in Laravel 10/Filamentphp 3 app in app/Casts/MoneyCast.php :

```
namespace App\Casts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MoneyCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes): float
    {
        // Transform the integer stored in the database into a float.
        return round(floatval($value) / 100, precision: 2);
    }

    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes): float
    {
        // Transform the float into an integer for storage.
        return round(floatval($value) * 100);
    }
}
```

I got valid results with model app/Models/Employee.php :

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';
        = [
             'salary' => MoneyCast::class,
        ];
```

But using in Resource table :

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('salary')
    ->currency('USD')
    ->icon(static fn (Employee $record) => $record->getAttribute('salary') > 500 ? 'heroicon-o-currency-dollar' : '')
    ->tooltip(static fn (Employee $record) => $record->getAttribute('salary') > 500 ? 'High salary ' . $record->getAttribute('salary') : ''),
```

As result salary field correctly shown in table value, but invalid value in hint text :

[image]

Also condition also does not work correctly, as salary value rendered correctly...

What is wrong and that can be fixed ?

**Updated block :**
No that did not help. Using direct access to fields istead of getAttribute

```
    Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('salary')
        ->currency('USD')
        ->icon(static fn (Employee $record) => $record->salary > 500 ? EmployeeHelper::getHighSalaryIcon() : '')
        ->tooltip(static fn (Employee $record) => $record->salary > 500 ? 'High salary ' . $record->salary : ''),
```

both condition in icon does not work correctly and text in hint is rendered incorectltly, without casting as money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$record->getAttribute('salary')` bypasses the accessor, which is great for the `$record->getAttribute('salary') > 500` comparison, which needs real numbers, but not so great for the resulting output.

Change:

```
tooltip(static fn (Employee $record) => $record->getAttribute('salary') > 500
  ? 'High salary ' . $record->getAttribute('salary') : ''),
```

to:

```
tooltip(static fn (Employee $record) => $record->getAttribute('salary') > 500
  ? 'High salary ' . $record->salary : ''),
```

Comment: Please read Updated block

Comment: @mstdmstd Have you tried the `currency` helper in Laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-number-currency

Comment: No Number::currency did not help as it does not know that I use 
    

    return round(floatval($value) / 100, precision: 2);


rule, so outputted results are invalid...

Comment: @mstdmstd Sure it will. `? 'High salary ' . Number::currency($record->salary) : '')`